# t: Instance org.acme.seller.Car#HW7722 missing required field oldOwner

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm new into blockchain and I was trying some code on hyperledger-composer setup I have installed on Ubuntu using virtual box, but couldn't resolve this error.

I'm receiving this error while submitting transaction:

t: Instance org.acme.seller.Car#HW7722 missing required field oldOwner

### Below is the code I was trying:

```
**Sample.cto**
/**
 * Sample business network definition.
 */
namespace org.acme.seller

asset Car identified by carNumber{
  o String carNumber
  o String carName
  --> Owner oldOwner
}


participant Owner identified by ownerId{
  o String ownerId
  o String fname
  o String lname
}

transaction Transfer{
  --> Car car
  --> Owner newOwner
}
----------------------
**Sample.js**

/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.acme.seller.Transfer} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
function Transfer(tx) {

    // Save the old value of the asset.
    tx.car.oldOwner = tx.car.newOwner;

    // Update the asset with the new value.
     // tx.car1.value = tx.newValue;

    // Get the asset registry for the asset.
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.seller.Car')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {

            // Update the asset in the asset registry.
            return assetRegistry.update(tx.car);
        });
}
------------------------------------------------
**Permissions.acl**

/**
 * Sample access control list.
 */
rule EverybodyCanReadEverything {
    description: "Allow all participants read access to all resources"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.seller.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule EverybodyCanSubmitTransactions {
    description: "Allow all participants to submit transactions"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.seller.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule OwnerHasFullAccessToTheirAssets {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their assets"
    participant(p): "org.acme.seller.*"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.acme.seller.*"
    condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error if you have added a new field to an Asset and have existing data in the asset registry without that field.

If you add optional to the new field e.g. `--> Owner oldOwner optional` that error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to have a **Bootstrap function** that helps you to load few assets and participants for testing your function. Here in your case, the transaction needs **owner participant** that you should have created before. This helps in transferring the car from one owner to another owner.

Considering the case, do the following rather than making it optional as mentioned by @r-thatcher. **Create two owners** and then try making the transaction by giving the owner id when transacting. This will help you to understand it clearly.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for reply.I was trying to do same and was getting error. I have created two owners, one currently owns the asset and one asset as car and after submitting transaction i am assigning another to first one.

Comment: t: Instance org.acme.seller.Car#HW7722 missing required field oldOwner          above is the code on which i'm working on

Comment: When you first create the car, are you filling the oldOwner(make it Owner if possible because it makes sense) with any Owner record??